# Upload Image after checking size,width & height

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I want to upload an image after checking the image size, width and height but my script has errors.

**Code:**

```
<?php
  include('dbcon.php');
  $name=$_POST["name"];
  $tel=$_POST["tel"];

  //upload file syntax begining
  $fileField=$_FILES["fileField"]["name"];

  if($_FILES["fileField"]["size"] >= 50000) {
    echo "bigfile";
  }
  elseif {
    $fileField = @getimagesize($_FILES["fileField"]["tmp_name"]);
    ($fileField === FALSE || !($fileField[2] == IMAGETYPE_GIF || $fileField[2] == IMAGETYPE_JPEG || $fileField[2] == IMAGETYPE_PNG)); 
    echo "Only Allow jpeg,PNG,Gif";

  { 
  else{ 
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileField"]["tmp_name"],"upload/".$_FILES["fileField"]["name"]);
    //upload file syntax ending
    $sql="insert into imgtb(name,tel,image)values('$name','$tel','$fileField')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
  }
?>
```

Someone please help to fix errors!

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to the below:

```
<?php
include('dbcon.php');
$name = $_POST["name"];
$tel = $_POST["tel"];

$fileField = $_FILES["fileField"]["name"];

if($_FILES["fileField"]["size"] >= 50000) {
    echo "big image";
} else {
    $fileField = @getimagesize($_FILES["fileField"]["tmp_name"]);
    if ($fileField === FALSE || !($fileField[2] == IMAGETYPE_GIF || $fileField[2] == IMAGETYPE_JPEG || $fileField[2] == IMAGETYPE_PNG)) {
        echo "Only Allow jpeg,PNG,Gif";
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileField"]["tmp_name"],"upload/".$_FILES["fileField"]["name"]);

        $sql="insert into imgtb(name,tel,image)values('$name','$tel','$fileField')";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
    }
}
?>
```

Note: You have so many syntax error. Escape all the variables before inserting into DB.